# less.js crash javascript function

Tags: javascript, jquery, less

I'm using less.js to my project. Sometimes less.js work immediately, sometimes work after my javascript codes.

when less work after code i can get element height or offset values.

```
Rendered http://localhost/css/main.less successfully.
CSS for http://localhost/css/main.less generated in 143ms
Less has finished. CSS generated in 144ms
***********
element : #introduction
height : 228
```

but when less work before codes all values are zero.

```
element : #introduction
height : 0
***********
Rendered http://localhost/css/main.less successfully.
CSS for http://localhost/css/main.less generated in 143ms
Less has finished. CSS generated in 144ms
```

When element height in setTimemout function its work because this codes working after less.js

```
setTimeout(function() {
    console.log($(element).height());
}, 0);
```

How can i fix that?